# Manipulation Events not firing on webBrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, manipulationdelta

I want ManipulationDelta event to fire when I touch(multi-touch) on the webpage opened in a WPF application using webBrowser control . But Manipulation events are not firing.
Xaml:

```
 <WebBrowser x:Name="myBrowser" Grid.Row="1" ManipulationDelta="myBrowser_ManipulationDelta" />
```

C#

```
 private void myBrowser_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation != 0)
            {
                 //Perform some action
            }

            else
            {
                //Perform some action
            }
        }
```

I think the events dont fire on webBroser control as all the events redirect to webpage. How can I acheive my requirement then?

Please help!!